# autocomplete how to make it run

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsp, struts2, autocomplete

I'm stuck with jQuery autocomplete ([I am trying this example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp))

I'm not getting what the problem is: no message is displaying in browser console.

URL is getting called and output at server side is printed properly.

The autocomplete is not showing in JSP page.

JSP page

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
        .ui-autocomplete-loading {
            background: white url('images/loader.gif') right center no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
       <span class="label">Names</span>
       <span class="ib"> <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/></span>
    </div>
<script>
  $(function() {
        function log( message ) {
            $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
            $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
        }

        $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/cxn/test",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: request,
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data.names, function( item ) {
                            console.log(item);
                            return {
                                label: item.names,
                                value: item.names
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                     error: function( data ) {
                           alert(data.names);
                           console.log(data);
                           alert('error');    
                   }

                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            },
            open: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
            },
            close: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
            }
        });
    });

</script> 
</body>
```

in action config

```
<action name="test" class="iland.supplier.SupplierAction" method="test">
            <result  type="json"></result>
        </action>
```

in actionClass

```
 public class SupplierAction extends ActionSupport {
    private ArrayList Names;
    //getter and setter of names
     public String test() {
            ArrayList<String> sss = new ArrayList<String>();
            sss.add("Manish");
            sss.add("Manoj");
            sss.add("Mohan");
            sss.add("Madhuri");
            sss.add("Mayank");
            sss.add("Mitesh");
            sss.add("Mitali");
            setNames(sss);
            for (String s : sss) {
                System.out.println(" " + s);
            }

            return SUCCESS;
        }
}
```

This is my json data for that i am trying above autocomplete. I want auto complete for names
[image]

Here

```
error: function( data ) {
                               alert(data.names);
                               console.log(data);
                               alert('error');    
                       }
```

error is get called 
 `alert(data.names) is undefined`
and in console it is printing as follows
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the Getter. And the variable name starting with an uppercase letter is preventing it to be found anyway. 
No need for the second ArrayList too, and there is a typo in action code (I'm assuming `private Names;` is `private List<String> Names;`).

It should be like this:

```
private List<String> names;

public List<String> getNames(){
    return names;
}

public String test() {

    names = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("Manish");
        add("Manoj");
        add("Mohan");
        add("Madhuri");
        add("Mayank");
        add("Mitesh");
        add("Mitali");
    }};

    for (String s : names) {
        System.out.println(" " + s);
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Yes that is there It was my writing mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `response`.

```
 response( $.map( data.names, function( item ) {
 return {
    label: item,
    value: item
    }
 }));
```

Since your `data.names` array is an array of strings, there are no properties. So just use `item` in your response function.

Comment: I tried  `error: function( data ) {alert('error');}`. This is executing. how to correct it

Comment: Please see updated question. In console i am getting above OP

Comment: Is the response a `string` or `object`? `console.log(typeof data);` should answer that question.

Comment: Hi @joeFletch its object

Comment: Looks like Andrea has your answer. Please do not forget to mark that as your answer so that this question is answered.

Comment: No it was not answer. I just made change and got output :).Feeling so happy

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

1. Mark your method (`test()`) as ajaxMethod like below. You need to include Ajax namespace:

   ```
   using Ajax; 
   [Ajax.AjaxMethod]
   public String test()
   {
       your code...
   }
   ```
2. Add below two lines in your Page in Page_Load event:

   ```
   using Ajax;
   Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(SupplierAction.test));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed

```
   dataType: "jsonp",
```

to

```
  dataType: "json",
```